# Get image from Contact Swift

Tags: swift, ios10

**Desired Behavior**

I am wondering how to best do the following in Swift

> 1. Display a contact picker window
> 2. Allow a user to select a contact
> 3. Fetch an image from that contact.

**Research**

In researching this question, I have determined that, beginning in iOS 9, Apple introduced a new framework, `Contacts`, for accessing contacts. I also learned that [Their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts) describes using a system called `Predicates` for fetching information from a contact. However, I am unsure of how to implement this.

**Implementation**

[Based primarly on this tutorial](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios9-day-by-day-day7-contacts-framework), I have figured out how to present the Contacts Picker window.

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

class ViewController: UIViewController,  CNContactPickerDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func contactsPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self;

    self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
   //Here is where I am stuck - how do I get the image from the contact?
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are three properties related to contact images according to the [API reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontact) from apple:

> Image Properties
>
> var imageData: Data? The profile picture of a contact.
>
> var thumbnailImageData: Data?  The thumbnail version of the contact’s profile picture.
>
> var imageDataAvailable: Bool   Indicates whether a contact has a profile picture.

You can get the CNContact instance from CNContactProperty, and then access  `imageData` in [CNContact](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontact) class.

So your code may look like this:

```
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
   let contact = contactProperty.contact
   if contact.imageDataAvailable {
      // there is an image for this contact
      let image = UIImage(data: contact.imageData)
      // Do what ever you want with the contact image below
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in SwiftUI this struct creates Rounded contact image.

create a struct;

```
struct ContactImage:View{
    let contact:CNContact!
    let size:CGFloat?
    var body:some View{
        if contact.imageData != nil {
            
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: contact.imageData!)!)
                .resizable()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding(.all,2)
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2))
                
                .frame(width: size ?? 28, height: size ?? 28, alignment: .center)
                
                
    
                   
        }else{
            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                .resizable()
                .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding(.all,2)
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2))
                        .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: size ?? 28, height: size ?? 28, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

and call it in your main body and define height and width according to your need

```
 ContactImage(contact:contact,size:nil)
```

and result

[image]